# How to compare lists ranges where a repeated index will cause a difference in length in Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, compare

I am trying to compare two lists, where one is a list of inputted guesses, and the other is a randomly selected word from a .txt file. It works until the random word contains more than one instance of a letter (Such as 'seek' contains 2 'e's') which will then cause a difference in the length of each list and re-enters the loop instead of outputting as correct.

As a part of a Hangman game. I have tried turning each list into a .counter but it seems you cannot directly compare 2 counters with '=='. I have tried setting a function that will add a second letter for any that are repeated, but I couldn't get it to work, however it could quite easily be my inept coding ability.

```
random_word = list(random.choice(open("word_list.txt").read().split()))    


if len(correct_guess_list) == len(random_word):       
            print("Congratulations you win")
```

I want to compare the lengths of each list and when the lengths are the same to output as true. It only works for words without the same letter repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up adding both the 'random_word' and the user inputted letters to their own sets which won't allow duplicates, and then comparing the length of each to one another so that when they are the same length the if statement outputs True.